# Strrep not working in Matlab to make String into function

Tags: string, matlab, str-replace, numerical, equation-solving

Hello I am new to MATLAB , I wanted to know **how can I make my string into function** . I want to access the function as a string from user in standard Matlab format (e.g `exp(-10*X)-sin(pi*X)-2*tanh(X)` ) Here X is the variable. Then I want to replace 'X' with 'low' and 'high' variables to calculate value of function at these limits. I have used 'strrep' for this purpose. I am getting the following errors
1)Undefined function or variable 'X'.
2) I cannot see whether 'X' was replaced with 'low' and 'high'.

Any help will be truly appreciated.
Below is my code.

```
    high=input('Upper Limit of the Interval : ');

    low=input('\nLower Limit of the interval : ');

    usr_funct=input('Enter The Function in standard Matlab Format.\nEnter "X" for the
    variable and * for multiply \n');    % Example exp(-10*X)-sin(pi*X)-2*tanh(X);

    middle = (low+high)/2;

    Flow =strrep(usr_funct, 'X', 'low');
    Fhigh =strrep(usr_funct, 'X', 'high');

   sprintf('Flow '); % This was to check if 'X' was replaced with 'low'. It is not printing anything
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the **eval function**. That will evaluate a string as matlab code.

Here is an example:

```
str = 'exp(-10*X)-sin(pi*X)-2*tanh(X)' ; % let str be your math expression
high = 10; % Ask the user
low = -5; % Ask the user

% Now we evaluate for High and Low
X = low; % We want to evaluate for low
ResultLow = eval(str); % That will return your value for X = low
X = high; % We want to evaluate for low
ResultHigh = eval(str); % That will return your value for X = high
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
usr_funct=input('Enter The Function...', 's');
```

This will return the entered text as a MATLAB string, without evaluating expressions.

Answer (score 2):

1) Undefined function or variable 'X'

If you look at the documentation for [`input`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html), it says that by default, it evaluates the expression. You need to add a second argument of 's' for it to just save a string.

2) I cannot see whether 'X' was replace with 'low' and 'high'

You should type `sprintf(Flow)` instead of `sprintf('Flow')`. The latter will just output "Flow" onto the screen while the former will output the value of Flow.

Finally, the [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) function may be of use later on when you actually want to evaluate your expression.